# Find a Wildcard Match in an Array with PowerShell

Tags: powershell, user-accounts, array

I have a list of users I want to do an ActiveDirectory lookup on but I don't want to do a lookup on System accounts that pop into my list. My list I am checking against will have the fullname of user account. I'd like to check against that list using a predictable pattern.

The code I am writing currently looks something like this:

```
$Usertest = "BUILTIN\Administrator"
$SystemUsers = @(
    'NT AUTHORITY\*',
    'BUILTIN\*',
    'S-*',
    'Everyone'
 )
if ($SystemUsers -contains $UserTest)
{
    Write-Host "$Usertest is a system or deleted account"
}
else
{
    Write-Host "$Usertest exists in Active Directory"
}
```

Obviously the code above does not work but it does convey what I am trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Afternoon,

You had a few things wrong with what you were trying to do:

### Single Quotes

```
$SystemUsers = @(
    'NT AUTHORITY\*',
    'BUILTIN\*',
    'S-*',
    'Everyone'
 )
```

Single quotes are literal strings and arent interperated.  In this case, you would be looking for a user called `NT Authority\*`.  By changing these to double quotes - you will start matching patterns.  For more information see [About Quoting Rules](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_quoting_rules?view=powershell-6) on Microsoft's Documentation website.

---

### Escaping

In PowerShell, the "\" is an escape character.  To escape your slashes - double them up:

```
$SystemUsers = @(
    "NT AUTHORITY\\*",
    "BUILTIN\\*",
    "S-1*",
    "Everyone"
 )
```

For more information on this - have a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37001694/how-to-handle-backslash-character-in-powershell-replace-string-operations/37001885) on Stack OverFlow.  Also, matching against `S-*` will give you loads of matches you don't want, try `"S-1*"`.  Windows SIDs havent really changed since [windows 2000 days](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc962011.aspx) so this is a fairly safe thing to do

---

### Loop Through The Array

In short - a string will not compare to an array when using wild cards.  [This article](https://www.codykonior.com/2013/01/10/powershell-how-to-search-a-list-of-objects-with-an-array-of-wildcards/) demonstrates this for you.

The easiest way to compare all items in your array is to loop through the array:

`ForEach ($SystemUser in $SystemUsers) { 
}`

---

### Match not Contains

Match is a much better way of matching an item in an array.  Microsoft's [About Comparison Operators](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_comparison_operators?view=powershell-6) page will give you a jump start, but there's loads more to it than this.  Try something like:

```
ForEach ($SystemUser in $SystemUsers) {
    if ($Usertest -match $SystemUser)
    {
        Write-Host "$Usertest is a system or deleted account"
    }
    else
    {
        Write-Host "$Usertest exists in Active Directory"
    }
}
```

---

### Putting it all Together

```
$Usertest = "BUILTIN\Administrator"
$SystemUsers = @(
    "NT AUTHORITY\\*",
    "BUILTIN\\*",
    "S-1*",
    "Everyone"
 )

 ForEach ($SystemUser in $SystemUsers) {
    if ($Usertest -match $SystemUser)
    {
        Write-Host "$Usertest is a system or deleted account"
    }
    else
    {
        Write-Host "$Usertest exists in Active Directory"
    }
 }
```

This will give you a matching output:

> BUILTIN\Administrator exists in Active Directory
>
> BUILTIN\Administrator is a system or deleted account
>
> BUILTIN\Administrator exists in Active Directory
>
> BUILTIN\Administrator exists in Active Directory

...but this only half solves your problem - you only really care if you get a match, let alone 2, 3, or 4.  You also don't want to continue testing if you've found a match!  Extend it to include a swtch, move the line print to the end, and job done:

```
$Usertest = "BUILTIN\Administrator"
$SystemUsers = @(
   "NT AUTHORITY\\*",
   "BUILTIN\\*",
   "S-1*",
   "Everyone"
)

$HasUserBeenMatchedYet = $false
    ForEach ($SystemUser in $SystemUsers) {
        if ($Usertest -match $SystemUser) {
            $HasUserBeenMatchedYet = $true
            break
        }
    }

if ($HasUserBeenMatchedYet -eq $true) {
    Write-Host "$Usertest is a system or deleted account"
} else {
    Write-Host "$Usertest exists in Active Directory"
}
```

> BUILTIN\Administrator is a system or deleted account
>
> MyStupidFakeUser exists in Active Directory

---

### BONUS POINTS!

Stick the users to test in an array and loop through those too:

```
$Usertests = @("MyStupidFakeUser", "NT Authority\Someone")
$SystemUsers = @(
   "NT AUTHORITY\\*",
   "BUILTIN\\*",
   "S-1*",
   "Everyone"
)

ForEach ($UserTest in $userTests) {
    $HasUserBeenMatchedYet = $false
        ForEach ($SystemUser in $SystemUsers) {
            if ($Usertest -match $SystemUser) {
                $HasUserBeenMatchedYet = $true
                break
            }
        }

    if ($HasUserBeenMatchedYet -eq $true) {
        Write-Host "$Usertest is a system or deleted account"
    } else {
        Write-Host "$Usertest exists in Active Directory"
    }
}
```

...now all you have to do is actually test if they are in AD - [have a look at Get-ADUser in PowerShell](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/addsadministration/get-aduser?view=win10-ps)

Comment: I got an error `parsing "*admin" - Quantifier {x,y} following nothing.` but `if ("A$Usertest -match "A$SystemUser")` works.